# Is it possible to create a table into Amazon Web Services?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm newbie in `Amazon Web Services(AWS)`. I'm want to create table in **Storage S3** and continuously store data from **Raspberry PI** to **AWS** using Python. **Is it possible to create a table into Storage S3 and continuously add entity?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did google and found the solution.

I have created table into **DynamoDB** Database.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto3


Dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-1', aws_access_key_id='your_key', aws_secret_access_key='your_secret_key')

table = Dynamodb.create_table(
            TableName=self.TName,
            KeySchema=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'ID',
                'KeyType': 'HASH'
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'RowKey',
                'KeyType': 'RANGE'
            }
            ],
            AttributeDefinitions=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'ID',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'RowKey',
                'AttributeType': 'N'
            },

            ],
            ProvisionedThroughput={
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
            }
        )

Table.put_item(
           Item={
            'RowKey': key,          
            'Rpi_ID': ID,
            'Name': 'Msc',
            #'account_type': 'standard_user',
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create table and insert data into it, You can use Amazon dynamo db [link to dynamo db](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) .

Amazon s3 is simple key value based data storage , Its not a database like Dynamo db , You can read more about Amazon S3 here [amazon s3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html)